# A question of mapping about power sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

Let h: A → B be a function from a set A to a set B. The function h can be used to
construct a function H: (A) → (B) as follows: For each X ∈ (A)
, H(X) = h(X) (i.e. the image set of  , by ℎ ).
Show that  is one-to-one ⇔ ℎ is one-to-one.

I've tried "$\Leftarrow$" like following

Suppose that h is injective that h(x)=h(y) $\Rightarrow$ x=y, for x,y belongs to A. Since A $\subseteq$ (A), x and y belongs to (A). While h(x) = H(x) for x ∈ (A), so I prove that H(x)=H(y) $\Rightarrow$ x=y, which implies to H is injective

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: @Mariacosta My question is to prove that  is one-to-one ⇒ ℎ is one-to-one.

Comment: $\Leftarrow$ This part of your proof is not complete. Assuming $H(X) = H(Y)$, we must show that $X = Y$, using the hypothesis that $h$ is injective. Following our assumption, we must have: $\{h(x) | x \in X \} = \{h(y) | y \in Y\}$, by injectivity of $h$, which implies that $X = Y$. Hence $H$ is injective. The sufficiency follows a similar logic.

Comment: @ShahinNosratJogan I show my prove of sufficiency to you. Assuming h(x)=h(y) and x=y must be shown. Using the hypothesis that H is injective, we have {H(x)|x∈X}={H(y)|y∈Y}, which implies that x=y, hence h(x)=h(y)⇒ x=y and h is injective

Comment: @SaltedFishKing Almost there! Letting $h(x) = h(y) \forall x, y$, then this implies $H(X) = \{h(x) | x \in X \} = \{h(y) | y \in Y \} = H(Y)$. I think you should be able to use the hypothesis; namely that $H$ is injective to reach the conclusion.